# Getting 400 (Bad Request) with my firebase URL

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am coming to an issue where I am trying to do a PUT request to update and store data to my firebase database, but for some reason when I run my code and select on my object and click on next, I get error with my firebase web request url as a 400 (Bad Request) error. does anyone how to solve this issue. thanks for the help.

PS: HIDDEN_URL is just a text - I hide my project url for security purposes. Thanks!

-The hardcode values work: `"{\"messages\":{\"message\":\"This is a test\"}}";` but not `lastHighlightedObject.GetComponent<OBClick>().name;`

Here is my code:

```
    public void NextButton()
    {
        if (highlightSet == true)
        {
             var httpWebRequest =
                (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://HIDDEN_URL.firebaseio.com/brokenComp.json");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";


            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                 string missingObjectCount = lastHighlightedObject.GetComponent<OBClick>().name;
                 streamWriter.Write(missingObjectCount);

            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.Log(result);

            } 

            // When everything is Okay, it will load the scene. 
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Quiz");
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Firebase Unity SDK?

Comment: yes I have considered using firebase unity sdk. But first I want to retrieve the name in order I can upload to firebase

Comment: Before asking around the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58753497/7111561) you should probably work on the one you already have. You didn't upvote/accept any answer there yet.. did you solve your problem?

Comment: @GaryJackson if you used the Firebase SDK you could retrieve the anme from a query with a singe line of code.

Comment: @ErikOverflow As I actually showed in the last question that's why I'm asking ;)

Comment: This question as you see - I have updated. I fixed the previous one but this ones is getting a 400 bad request error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service seems to require a certain JSON format. Since your hardcore version works

> ```
> "{\"messages\":{\"message\":\"This is a test\"}}";
> ```

but not a single `string` I guess you have to use something like

```
 string missingObjectCount = "{\"messages\":{\"message\":\"" + HighlightedObject.GetComponent<OBClick>().name + "\"}}"
```

---

As mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753497/accessing-static-member-to-another-class-not-working):

Currently your code will freeze until the request is done.

I would rather use either [`UnityWebRequest.Put`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Put.html) to not block the entire thread until the request is done.

This is just the example (with small edits) from the API but I guess it js pretty straight forward and you should be able to use it for your purpose

```
public class MyBehavior : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void NextButton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        byte[] myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"messages\":{\"message\":\"" + HighlightedObject.GetComponent<OBClick>().name + "\"}}");
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put(YOUR_URL, myData))
        {
            yield return www.Send();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Upload complete!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Btw is something hindering you from using the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data)?

There it would be something like

```
public class MyScript: MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    private void Start() 
    {
        // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/");

        // Get the root reference location of the database.
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }

    public void NextButton()
    {
        // ported the variable names from your latest question
        mDatabaseRef.Child("messages").Child("message").SetValueAsync(HighlightedObject.GetComponent<OBClick>().name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see @derHugo Thank you so much sir.

Comment: I just ported the `FirebaseSDK` and `UnityWebRequest` solution here so I think you could close(delete) your previous question.

Comment: okay. is there a way with my code above to store as a list, as in instead of selecting one object - the user selects multiple objects?